# How to encrypt a message to Blowfish using OpenSSL?

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl, blowfish

I need to get the Blowfish encryption with OpenSSL library. But something does not work.
What am I doing wrong? I'm trying to do it this way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <openssl/blowfish.h>
#include "OpenSSL_Base64.h"
#include "Base64.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned char ciphertext[BF_BLOCK];
    unsigned char plaintext[BF_BLOCK];

    // blowfish key
    const unsigned char *key = (const unsigned char*)"topsecret";
    //unsigned char key_data[10] = "topsecret";
    BF_KEY bfKey;
    BF_set_key(&bfKey, 10, key);

    /* Open SSL's Blowfish ECB encrypt/decrypt function only handles 8 bytes of data */
    char a_str[] = "8 Bytes";//{8, ,B,y,t,e,s,\0}
    char *arr_ptr = &a_str[0];

    //unsigned char* data_to_encrypt = (unsigned char*)"8 Bytes"; // 7 + \0

    BF_ecb_encrypt((unsigned char*)arr_ptr, ciphertext, &bfKey, BF_ENCRYPT);

    unsigned char* ret = new unsigned char[BF_BLOCK + 1];
    strcpy((char*)ret, (char*)ciphertext);
    ret[BF_BLOCK + 1] = '\0';

    char* base_enc = OpenSSL_Base64::Base64Encode((char*)ret, strlen((char*)ret));

    cout << base_enc << endl;

    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

But I get the wrong output:

```
fy7maf+FhmbM
```

I checked with it:

http://sladex.org/blowfish.js/

It should be: fEcC5/EKDVY=

Base64:

http://pastebin.com/wNLZQxQT

Comment: This question has been asked so many times... [openssl blowfish encryption example site:stackoverflow.com](http://www.google.com/search?q=openssl+blowfish+encryption+example+site%3Astackoverflow.com). `strlen((char*)ciphertext` does ***not*** work. Also see [EVP Symmetric Encryption and Decryption](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption) on the OpenSSL wiki. It even provides a C++ example of using it.

Comment: Not so much. I have seen most of the questions, and search in github for two days. All I found were incomplete, or give the wrong output, so I started from scratch. I'm trying to understand.

Comment: Of course Blowfish should not be used in new work, AES is the current choice.

Comment: @zaph, why? Blowfish fastest, I need to encrypt traffic of mobile online game.

Comment: @jww, ok, I changed the code a little bit, now {strlen} must work. But the output is still wrong: fy7maf+FhmbM

http://pastebin.com/u82UPwgV

Comment: Security, that is the point isn't it. And it may not be the faster, that depends on the hardware. On my phone I can AES encrypt 430 MB/s. A lot of hardware supports AES in some mannor from a few instructioins to a full implementation of AES.

Comment: @zaph thanks, I'll try AES, if I not make it to work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `ret` may contain a null byte, encryption is 8-bit byte based, not character based and will contain values fromthe full range 0-255. `strlen` will terminate on the first null byte it finds giving a length that is smaller then the full length of the encrypted data.

Note: When using encryption pay strice attention to providing the exact correct length parameters and data, do not rely on padding. (The exception is input data to encryption functions that support data padding such as PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding.

Comment: Incorrect length of the key (if I set manually 10 (length is 10!), only works with strlen().

BF_set_key(&bfKey, strlen((char*)key), key);

If the message is 8 bytes encrypts wrong, only if more than 8 =\
Сorrect encryption + a couple of garbage characters (not as if it was not \0). I still do not understand =\

Whan I understand, I accept your answer as correct, I may still have the questions. Thank you for helping!